# Test Passport's Authorization code grant authentication flow

Tags: laravel, api, testing, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

Any idea on how i can test my authentication routes in authorization code grant:
- GET: '/oauth/authorize/?' . $query
- POST: 'oauth/token'

The problem is that according to the docs you need to provide a redirect_uri field in your query and i don't know how you suppose to have one in tests and then get the response from your laravel app.

i don't want to test this api with my frontend app.(if possible)

i haven't showed any code bc i just need a general idea of the testing process of such APIs that are working with clients and redirect_uris

on google i found tests around password grant authentication which doesn't need a redirect_uri field

this is what i tryed and it failed.
test:

```
$user = User::orderBy('id', 'asc')->first();
$token = $user->createToken('personal_access');
Passport::actingAs($user, [], 'api');

(new AuthController)->logout();

if (($user = Auth::user()->toArray()) !== null) {
    dd(1, $user);
} else {
    dd(0);
}
```

Auth::user() returns the $user
AuthController:

```
public function logout(): Response
{
    $tokenId = $this->getTokenId();

    $tokenRepository = app(TokenRepository::class);
    $tokenRepository->revokeAccessToken($tokenId);

    $refreshTokenRepository = app(RefreshTokenRepository::class);
    $refreshTokenRepository->revokeRefreshTokensByAccessTokenId($tokenId);

    Artisan::call('passport:purge');

    return response('Successfully loged you out.', 200);
}

private function getTokenId(): int
{
    return (new CheckAuthentication)->getAuthenticated()->token()->id;
}
```

$tokenId is always zero.

Comment: The Idea behind Laravel Passport is you generate a client, then authenticate them by username, password and then you generate the token for this user which gets saved into the database, in the first login api if it was successfully You should respond with a bearer token and that must be further used in the requests from your Application.

Comment: i know @Malik Waqas but i'm using it as my only way to authenticate my first parties. the logout route revokes all the tokens and login creates an access token, no refresh token and access tokens expire in 1 hour

Comment: as a result i will have a flexible api authentication, i can add as many frontends as i want

Comment: You want to have redirect_uri in your authentication request and user must be redirected back to that uri ? or you want to register some sort of callback on this redirect_uri to push events on it ?

Comment: i'm talking about this redirect_uri field in this laravel doc: [link](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#requesting-tokens-converting-authorization-codes-to-access-tokens)

Comment: how can i test that, get the response of my laravel app when it's sending the response to another uri (the authorization code grant type flow)

Comment: use `postman` ?

Comment: thanks @Malik Waqas but idon't know how should i fill that field in my get requests to /oauth/authorize anyway i have postman and i'm working with docker compose

Comment: if you post some code form server side endpoint of authorize and the client side from where you want to make the request we can help more

Comment: try this website: https://webhook.site/ It will give you a temporary link which you can use as callback and if your server sends some response on your request here you will be able to check the triggered response.

Comment: @Malik Waqas the point of this question is i get an idea of some kind of tests that don't depend on client side apps, and what codes do you need from backend? there is really only passport routes, how can i test them is my question.

Comment: @Malik Waqas thanks that helps but still anything better?

Comment: hmm I would assume you already have test client username and passwords ? First step is to generate the token for your user you can do that by using the endpoint for login